# Reading invalid xml with xDocument or XmlDocument c#

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xmldocument

I have situation where I have used xslt to transform xml file.

Now I need to modify the result xml file which is not valid xml and xml parsers are not able to read it.

It doesn't start with xml declaration and there is no one root for the file.

I cannot change the structure of the file as that is another standard that I need to use but I need to add node inside the valid xml and also get information from specific node.

I already tried to use Like this

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.XmlResolver = null;
doc.Load(InputFile);
doc.DocumentElement;
```

With this I only got stuff from inside the invalid XML but not from inside the valid XML

What I would really need is list of "validXmlWithDeclaration" nodes

structure is something like this.

```
<invalidXMLWithoutDeclaration>
 <foo>
  <bar>
  </bar>
 </foo>
</invalidXMLWithoutDeclaration>
<validXmlWithDeclaration>
 <foo>
  <bar>
  </bar>
 </foo>
</validXmlWithDeclaration>
<invalidXMLWithoutDeclaration>
 <foo>
  <bar>
  </bar>
 </foo>
</invalidXMLWithoutDeclaration>
<validXmlWithDeclaration>
 <foo>
  <bar>
  </bar>
 </foo>
</validXmlWithDeclaration>
<invalidXMLWithoutDeclaration>
 <foo>
  <bar>
  </bar>
 </foo>
</invalidXMLWithoutDeclaration>
<validXmlWithDeclaration>
 <foo>
  <bar>
  </bar>
 </foo>
</validXmlWithDeclaration>
```

Comment: Why are some nodes valid and others are not?

Comment: The term valid is used to define whether an XML document conforms to a DTD or schema. If you have fragments which are not well-formed XML then you can't load them with `XmlDocument`, you can however use an `XmlDocumentFragment`, for instance by setting the `InnerXml` property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocumentfragment.innerxml(v=vs.110).aspx. Other options are using an `XmlReader` with the `XmlReaderSettings.ConformanceLevel` set as `Fragment` and then passing the XmlReader to an `XPathDocument`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that parses the snippet you have shown by settings the `InnerXml` property of an `XmlDocumentFragment` and selects some of the elements in it:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDocumentFragment fragment = doc.CreateDocumentFragment();
        fragment.InnerXml = @"<invalidXMLWithoutDeclaration>
 <foo>
  <bar>
  </bar>
 </foo>
</invalidXMLWithoutDeclaration>
<validXmlWithDeclaration>
 <foo>
  <bar>
  </bar>
 </foo>
</validXmlWithDeclaration>
<invalidXMLWithoutDeclaration>
 <foo>
  <bar>
  </bar>
 </foo>
</invalidXMLWithoutDeclaration>
<validXmlWithDeclaration>
 <foo>
  <bar>
  </bar>
 </foo>
</validXmlWithDeclaration>
<invalidXMLWithoutDeclaration>
 <foo>
  <bar>
  </bar>
 </foo>
</invalidXMLWithoutDeclaration>
<validXmlWithDeclaration>
 <foo>
  <bar>
  </bar>
 </foo>
</validXmlWithDeclaration>";
        foreach (XmlElement el in fragment.SelectNodes("validXmlWithDeclaration"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(el.OuterXml);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just don't have a well formed xml file.  See my solution below with XmlRead and XDocument

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication62
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);

            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "invalidXMLWithoutDeclaration")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("invalidXMLWithoutDeclaration");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement invalidXMLWithoutDeclaration = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```